# How to keep score for questions answered correct and deduct points for questions answered wrong?

Tags: javascript, loops, input, output, do-while

Working with the do while loop, I'm trying to keep score for questions answered correct and would like to deduct points for questions answered incorrect. I'm sure there is a way to do this, I guess I just need a bit of help.

```
var answer1 = "Batman";
var answer = false;
do {
   var guess = prompt("Who is knows as the Caped Crusader?");
    if (guess == answer1) {
      alert("Yes, you got it right! The Caped Crusader is known as " + answer1 + " You get 1 point!");
      answer = true;
    }
  else {
    alert("Sorry, wrong hero. Try again!");
  }
}
while (answer == false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a variable keeping score. Add 1 to it to add points and subtract 1 to deduct points.

```js
var answer1 = "Batman";
var answer = false;
var score = 0;

do {
  var guess = prompt("Who is knows as the Caped Crusader?");
  if (guess == answer1) {
    alert("Yes, you got it right! The Caped Crusader is known as " + answer1 + " You get 1 point!");
    score++;
    answer = true;
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, wrong hero. Try again!");
    score--;
  }
}
while (answer == false);

alert("Your score is: " + score);
```

Comment: This helps, thanks buddy. Hate to ask silly questions but I am a noob here, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: @Designird of course. I'm always happy to help. Make sure to accept the answer if it worked for you to let others know it worked as well. And there's no such thing as a silly question.